# While in hiding, why did they have to apparate on the top step of Grimmauld Place entrance (and not directly inside)?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition, grimmauld-place

As Dumbledore once explained Harry, people usually apparate in front of the house (or around the house, at least not in it) they're visiting for two reasons:

- it's rude to apparate directly into your host kitchen
- most houses have anti-apparating charms

> "Professor, why couldn't we just Apparate directly into your old colleague's house?"
>
> "Because it would be quite as rude as kicking down the front door," said Dumbledore. "Courtesy dictates that we offer fellow wizards the opportunity of denying us entry. In any case, most Wizarding dwellings are magically protected from unwanted Apparators.
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4 Horace Slughorn)*

But we know it's possible to apparate inside Grimmauld Place: George and Fred used to apparate from one room to the other:

> “We have,” said Hermione quickly. “We’ve been decontaminating this house, it’s been empty for ages and stuff’s been breeding in here. We’ve managed to clean out the kitchen, most of the bedrooms, and I think we’re doing the drawing room tomo — AARGH!”
>
> With two loud cracks, Fred and George, Ron’s elder twin brothers, had materialized out of thin air in the middle of the room.
> *(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 4, Number Twelwe Grimmauld Place)*

And about the politeness... When only Ron, Hermione and Harry are in the house, is it really rude for one of them to apparate inside the house (or even for Lupin)? Is it worth taking the risk to apparate on the stair, sometimes stumbling and letting the Invisibility Cloak slip, while Death Eaters are watching the place?

Lupin explaining he "had to" apparate on the top step, and telling about the watching Death Eaters:

> “Yes,” said Lupin, “but we’re all being watched. There are a couple of Death Eaters in the square outside—”
> “We know—”
> “I had to Apparate very precisely onto the top step outside the front door to be sure that they would not see me.
> *(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11, The Bribe)*

Harry almost being seen by the Death Eaters while coming back:

> Meanwhile, inside number twelve, Harry had just entered the hall. He had nearly lost his balance as he Apparated onto the top step just outside the front door, and thought that the Death Eaters might have caught a glimpse of his momentarily exposed elbow.
> *(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12, Magic is Might)*

Then explaining about it to Ron:

> “They nearly saw me coming back in just now,” Harry said. “I landed badly on the top step, and the Cloak slipped.”
> *(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12, Magic is Might)*

Comment: Maybe protection from apparition only affects apparition from outside the boundary of the building protected?

Comment: @TZHX I wondered so, but such a thing is never said... and if this was the case, people could apparate from Hogwarts to Hogwarts... in such a big place, I'm sure it would be useful - and used by teachers and elder students... (or inside the Ministry, to go to another floor without waiting for the elevator...)

Comment: Perhaps it's a feature / option on the spell? Disallowing apparition from point to point in a school / government building may make sense, when there's places there that are "restricted" (you wouldn't want your cleaner to be able to get into the vault / office of the Auror chief). In a family setting, such as a home, it's slightly less of an issue. Anyway, +1 for intersting question.

Comment: Like most magic stories, where most problems should be fixed with "more magic" - they do it to continue the dramatic tension. We know certain places, like Hogwarts or Vaults, are protected from Apparition (save the Apparition Training area & Dumbledore's headmaster bonus). It may also be something baked into their training, as going into a building from afar increases the possibility of splinching in a sort of reverse-telefragging style into a wall, or sofa, another person, et cetera

Comment: The bigger question to me is why don't wizards have a front room like a porch for guests to apparate to. It seems so logical to do that.

Comment: Just as an extra detail, I would assume that due to Grimmauld Place being protected by the __Fidelius Charm__, and the emphasis on landing on the top step, that the top step is protected by the charm, whilst the lower steps would not be (_and they would be seen by the death eaters watching the area_).

Comment: @agweber I always though the Fidelius Charm prevented them from Apparating directly in, so they landed just outside, and picked the top step so they could get in as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 44):

The simplest explanation is that one can Apparate within Grimmauld Place, but not to or from the building. There is precedent. In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, when the students are taking Apparition lessons:

> ‘As you may know, it is usually impossible to Apparate or  Disapparate
> within Hogwarts. The Headmaster has lifted this enchantment, purely
> within the Great Hall, for one hour, so as to enable you to practise.
> May I emphasize that you will not be able to Apparate outside the
> walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try.’
>
> <sub>Wilkie Twycross, *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* (Chapter 18, Birthday surprises)</sub>

Comment: An additional, if circumstantial, piece of evidence: the first (?) time Harry goes to the Burrow, we see Arthur arriving home from work by Apparition to the _outside_ of the house, and then coming in the door. But we also (during the same visit?) see Percy Apparating down for breakfast every morning just because he’s recently passed his Apparition test and _can_. It wouldn’t really be rude of Arthur to Apparate into his own home, so presumably the standard anti-Apparition charm does indeed only protect against Apparition across its external boundary.

Comment: Also it should be noted that Grimmauld place is Unplottable, although I admit to not knowing if that would affect apparition.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could also be that he does so out of habit and respect.  Apparition inside a building to another location inside the building might also be limited to residents (so a guest cannot easily rob you while your back is turned getting the tea).